# Django- VSCode - css loaded from static files "sticks" and does not respond to editing

Tags: html, css, django, visual-studio-code

Well this one is a head scratcher for me. I create a class in my style.css static file:

```
.not-visible {
    display:none;
    margin-top: 10px !important 
}
```

I then apply this class to a button and the button disappears

```
<div id = "btn-box" class = "not-visible">
            <button type = "submit" class = "ui primary `button">save</button>`
        </div>
```

I then edit my static css file to remove the display:none attribute to see if the button is visible again.

```
    .not-visible {
           margin-top: 10px !important 
}
```

After performing this operation, saving the css file, reloading the server, and restarting my web browser, the button is still no visible even though I deleted that property. When I delete the not-visible class in the button div, the button becomes visible gain.

if I repeat this exercise, except I code the css directly into the html file, to button disappears and reappears as expected when I add and then delete the display:none property. So my question is, howcome saved changes to static css files do not apply to my html file?

Comment: have you cleared the browsers cache? PS: You miss the semicolon at the end of the `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Just Add semicolon `;`
and try to remove `!important`
as following:

```
.not-visible {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the semi colon and removed important but the button is still not visible...

Comment: Please, provide me a source code, so I can help you efficiently